# I can't make TextInput to auto expand properly in Android

Tags: android, react-native

When I set `multiline` to `true`, on each new line, the content get pushed up, and there is a scroll that I can't disable.

[image]

In the attempt to fix it, I tried to set the height of the TextInput to the contentSize height that I get from `onContentSizeChange`, but there was a flicker on new lines.

[image]

the issue only happens on Android, `scrollEnabled` set to `false` seems to fix it in iOS

Do you have an idea how can I fix it?

PS: I don't want to set fixed `height` or `maxHeight`, the height should be flexible based on the content of the input